# WPS and WPA2 connection methods

Tags: encryption, wpa2, wps

Do clients use WPS every time when they connect to a WPS-enabled AP?
Or maybe they do it just the first time and then they switch to a normal WPA/WPA2 key exchange?

If the latter, it's possible for an AP to force a client to use WPS every time?

Answer (score 1):

WPS would generally only be used for the initial connection because the wireless network settings (pass-phrase/SSID) are saved on the connecting device. I don't know if it is possible to "force" clients to connect every time with WPS. If it is...I would not recommend it. WPS is insecure. A quick search for "WPS Hack" on a search engine will provide you with further information. Generally it is recommended that the WPS feature should be disabled.

Comment: Thank you Scott. I was asking because facking the AP in a evil twin scenario is much more effective than the classic half pin guessing algorithm